# Integrals involving the error function and the gaussian

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to know if the following integral has an explicit expression or not.
$$F(r)=\int_1^r \frac{1}{t^2}e^{t^2/2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)dt$$

where the error function inside is defined as

$$\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^t e^{-x^2/2}dx.$$

Thus,
$$F(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{1}^{r}\int_0^{t}\frac{1}{t^2}e^{\frac{t^2-x^2}{2}}dt dx$$
which on making a change of variable takes the form,
$$F(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_1^r\int_{0}^1 \frac{\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\left(1-y^2\right)\right)}{t}dy dt$$

Now
$$\int_1^r \frac{\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\left(1-y^2\right)\right)}{t} dt = \frac{1}{2}\left[\Gamma\left(0,\frac{y^2-2}{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(0,\frac{r^2(y^2-2)}{2}\right)\right].$$

To finish to computation one needs to compute,
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1\left[\Gamma\left(0,\frac{y^2-2}{2}\right)-\Gamma\left(0,\frac{r^2(y^2-2)}{2}\right)\right]dy,$$

but I am not sure how to compute expression involving the incomplete gamma function. I would like to know if there are any explicit expressions of the above integral involving the **Exponential Integral** or any other special function?

Comment: $\Gamma(0,x)$ is an Ei function like [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%280%2Cx%29++vs+-Ei%28-x%29)

Comment: Under the usual definition of erf, you should have a factor of $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ out front, not $1/\sqrt{\pi}$. Also the factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ seems to have escaped in the final equation, and for some reason the $1$ in $1-y^2$ turned into a $2$.

Comment: Mathematica gives: $\frac{r^2 \, _2F_2\left(1,1;2,\frac{5}{2};\frac{r^2}{2}\right)}{3 \sqrt{2 \pi }}-\frac{\, _2F_2\left(1,1;2,\frac{5}{2};\frac{1}{2}\right)}{3 \sqrt{2 \pi
   }}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \ln (r)$ if $r>=1$